# Flutter "inactivity disconnecting from the service" Error

Tags: flutter

When we run the application on the emulator, we can receive notifications while the application is running in the background, but when we build the application on a real device, we are faced with the error .

Error:

"inactivity disconnecting from the service"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use notification key in your fcm json, you can't recived background fcm data.

Try add this in fcm json;

```
'data': {'title': 'example'},
'content_available': true
```